# I'm getting an error when I try to use union

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```sql
SELECT avg(Product.product_price)
From product
Where (
  SELECT from customer
  customer.city = "Tucson"
  and Customer.cust_id = orders.cust_id
  and Product.product_id = Orderline.product_id
)
group by product_name

UNION

SELECT sum(product.product_price) 
From product
Where (
  SELECT from customer 
  customer.city = "Tucson"
  and Customer.cust_id = orders.cust_id
  and Product.product_id = Orderline.product_id
)
group by product_name
```

I'm trying to display the average order from customers who order from tucson and the sum of the products going to tuscon

I have these tables with these (rows )orders (order_id, order_date, cust_id), product (product_id, product_name, product_price), orderLine (order_id, product_id, quantity), customer (cust_id, cust_name, street, city, state, zip) I need to 8. Show the average price and total price of products bought by customers from ‘Tucson’(Use Union) –

Comment: what kind of error? please be more informative.

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; but I am also unsure if it's even the right query

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired reults.

Comment: Those error messages usually come with more information such as the specific location in your query. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64923295/edit) to provide **all** the relevant information

Comment: quickly view your query how come you got `select from` in those query... you need to specify what you want to select.

Comment: ... you're also missing some `WHERE` keywords in your sub-queries

Comment: I have these tables with these (rows )`orders` (`order_id`, `order_date`, `cust_id`), `product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `product_price`), `orderLine` (`order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`), `customer` (`cust_id`, `cust_name`, `street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) I need to 8. Show the average price and total price of products bought by customers from ‘Tucson’(Use
Union)

Comment: Did you write all that code without even trying it once during the process?!? Take smaller steps, write a simple select, verify, add where clause, verify, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with UNION - it's with the two queries you're attempting to UNION together. It looks to me like the AVG query should be something like:

```
SELECT avg(p.product_price)
  From product p
  INNER JOIN orderline ol
    ON ol.product_id = p.product_id
  INNER JOIN orders o
    ON o.??????? = ol.???????
  INNER JOIN customer c
    ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
  WHERE c.city = 'Tuscon'
```

What's not clear from the code you posted is how the `orders` and `orderline` tables are to be joined - that is, what the common field(s) are in those tables. You'll need to fill that in.

Make similar changes to your `SUM` query.